# Python Decorators and inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator

Help a guy out.  Can't seem to get a decorator to work with inheritance.  Broke it down to the simplest little example in my scratch workspace.  Still can't seem to get it working.

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 4
    def setVal(self,x):
        self.val = x
    def decor(self, func):
        def increment(self, x):
            return func( self, x ) + self.val
        return increment

class foo(bar):
    def __init__(self):
        bar.__init__(self)
    @decor
    def add(self, x):
        return x
```

Oops, name "decor" is not defined.

Okay, how about `@bar.decor`? TypeError: unbound method "decor" must be called with a bar instance as first argument (got function instance instead)

Ok, how about `@self.decor`?  Name "self" is not defined.

Ok, how about `@foo.decor`?! Name "foo" is not defined.

AaaaAAaAaaaarrrrgggg...  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your example, you could have `return x + self.val` for the definition of `add` in `foo`. Could you not do this in you actual code?

Comment: This is a distilled example code highlighting the issue I was facing.  If the code were that simple, then yes.  However, it's not.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Define `decor` as a static method and use the form `@bar.decor`:

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 4
    def setVal(self,x):
        self.val = x
    @staticmethod
    def decor(func):
        def increment(self, x):
            return func(self, x) + self.val
        return increment

class foo(bar):
    def __init__(self):
        bar.__init__(self)
    @bar.decor
    def add(self, x):
        return x
```

Comment: This works even better because `self` isn't used in both function definitions.

Comment: @EShull: Actually, `decor` can be a static method, despite the `self` reference.  `self` is only referenced inside `increment()`, and when invoking `f.add(10)` on a `foo` instance, the `self` parameter inside `increment()` will reference `f`, and the increment will work as expected.

Comment: This looks like it'll work.  Gotta leave work but if it does, I'm going to flag this as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Does this currently work? Does it not raise a `TypeError: staticmethod is not callable`?

Answer (score 3):

I know the question has been asked 11 years ago ...

I had the same problem, here is my solution to use an inherited private decorator :

```
class foo:
    def __bar(func):
        def wrapper(self):
            print('beginning')
            func(self)
            print('end')
        return wrapper

class baz(foo):
    def __init__(self):
        self.quux = 'middle'
    @foo._foo__bar
    def qux(self):
        print(self.quux)

a = baz()
a.qux()
```

The output is :

```
beginning
middle
end
```